# inflateException MainActivity.java.79

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle

Guys please my app is on play store and it works fine on some devices but i got complaint about crashes and found out its this highlighted line 7 thats causing the crashe all am try to do is check if there is internet connectivity the i show the main layout else if internet is off it opens another intent displaying no internet available.

My confusion is why its working for some people and others are expiriencing crashes
Please what am i doing wrong and how can i resolve this.
This my MainActivity

```
     boolean isConnected() {
    boolean internetAvailability = true;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

    }else {
    internetAvailability = false;
    }
    return internetAvailability;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      if (isConnected())
      {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");


    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DAILY BETS");






    //GETTING DATA INTO VIEW FROM FIREBASE

    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      betdataList.clear();
      if(dataSnapshot == null)
      {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing to Show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else {
          for (DataSnapshot betDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              Betdata bet = betDataSnapshot.getValue(Betdata.class);
              betdataList.add(bet);
          }

      }
      predictionsList = new CustomPredictionAdapter(betdataList,getApplicationContext(),resource);
      betList.setAdapter(predictionsList);
      betList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notification enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      if (betdataList.size() >0)
      {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    }


    );




    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_viewer);
   // boolean internetAvailability = true;



    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();
    progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Loading");
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    betList = findViewById(R.id.list);
    betdataList = new ArrayList<>();




    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    drawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    customDialog = new Dialog(this);

      }else {
          setContentView(R.layout.no_internet_layout);
          pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.pulldowntorefresh);
          pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
              @Override
              public void onRefresh() {
                  Intent restartIntent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                          .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                  restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                  startActivity(restartIntent);
                  pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

              }
          });
      }


    }
```

HERE IS CRASH REPORT FROM MY PLAY CONSOLE

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2572)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2654)   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11
>   (ActivityThread.java)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1488)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:111)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:789)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:679) Caused by: android.view.InflateException:    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView
>   (AppCompatActivity.java:139)   at
>   com.kenworld.bettingtipsapp.MainActivity.onCreate
>   (MainActivity.java:79)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
>   (Activity.java:6360)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1113)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2519) Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
>   (LayoutInflater.java:764)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
>   (LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate
>   (LayoutInflater.java:835)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:1566)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates
>   (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable
>   (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable
>   (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)   at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable
>   (AppCompatResources.java:100)   at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon
>   (MenuItemImpl.java:491)   at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems
>   (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:519)   at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update
>   (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:460)   at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView
>   (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:117)   at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu
>   (NavigationView.java:250)   at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.
>   (NavigationView.java:172)   at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.
>   (NavigationView.java:98)

Comment: You have a "Resources$NotFoundException", so check the drawables used for the NavigationView menu items. Maybe there's one which does not have a default version (in res/drawable)?

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Solved it by copying drawable-v21 files to drawable